# Digit-increasing number test

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, logic

A number is called digit-increasing if it is equal n + nn + nnn + ... for some digit n between 1 and 9. For example 24 is digit-increasing because it equals 2 + 22 (here n = 2).

Actually, a friend of mine asked me this question and i am stuck thinking about it but couldn't find the exact solution so far. Can anyone help ? I needed the function that returns true if it is digit-increasing else false.

Comment: I will answer if you don't require an answer in a particular language.

Comment: I just want the logic. Code in any language will do.

Comment: You just have 9 options to try from. It is either `(1+11+...)` or `(2+22+...)`... or `(9+99+...)`.

Comment: you can use modulo/division method for number separation.Like, 24/10=2 then multiply it by 10 so u get 20. then add quotient '2' to this '20' u get '22'. Now try to add '22' to quotient again then u get 24. if it equal to given number then it is digit-increasing. Just generalize it for N digits. Its simple.

Comment: Why closed it.. I just had one answer in C which is working ...

Comment: @Omkant I don't know why it is closed. You can vote to reopen. Anyway, you can comment the answer.

Comment: @SRJ I think the logic failed for digit with more than 2. I don't think it will work for 1+11+111 = 123.

Comment: @aneal Oh.Yes. Sorry about that. I just consider two digits. But as far as I know. Such problems like to be solved by same technique. (number separation using modulo division)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done in this way. Check out once.

```
int sum = 0, count =0;
bool flag = false;

public bool isDigitIncreasing(int input_number)
{
int  n= get_number_of_digit(input_number); // Gets number of digits
int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        sum = sum*10+1;
        count = count + sum;
    }

    for(int i=1; i<=9;i++)
    {
        if((input_number)==count*i)
        {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        flag = false;
    }
    return flag;

}

    public int get_number_of_digit(int num)
    {

        int size = 0;
        do
        {
            num = num/10;
            size++;
        }while(num>0);
        return size;
    }
```

Comment: unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 4):

There are only relatively few numbers with this property: Within the range of `unsigned long long` (64 bits), there are only 172 digit-increasing numbers.

Therefore, in terms of a practical solution, it makes sense to **pre-compute them all** and put them in a hash. Here is Python code for that:

```
# Auxiliary function that generates
# one of the 'nnnn' elements
def digits(digit,times):
  result = 0
  for i in range(times):
    result += digit*(10**i)
  return result

# Pre-computing a hash of digit-increasing
# numbers:
IncDig = {}
for i in range(1,30):
  for j in range(1,10):
    number = reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,[digits(j,k) for k in range(1,i+1)])
    IncDig[number] = None
```

Then the actual checking function is just a look-up in the hash:

```
def IncDigCheck(number):
  return (number in IncDig)
```

This is virtually O(1), and the time and space taken for the pre-calculation is minimal, because there are only 9 distinct digits (zero doesn't count), hence only `K*9` combinations of type `n + nn + ...` for a sum of length `K`.

Comment: Every O(n) algorithm is O(1) when n is restricted to some constant.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri That's not the point. The point is that the look-up in the hash does not depend on the size of the number you look up, and not even on the number of entries. (The latter is not completely true, depending on how the hash deals with collisions. That is why I said _virtually_ O(1).)

Comment: In Python, for integers, `hash(x) == x`, so it is easily possible that some of collisions are really bad.

Comment: @jogojapan, what's the benefit of this? at first you do a search as large as biggest numbers, then you saying it's O(1)? I'm pretty sure your algorithm is slower than any other exhaustive search presented in answers here, all of them are doing search till necessary, but you run it for all data.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri The first step isn't _search_. It's pre-calculation. You pre-calculate the 172 numbers that exist (assuming 64 bit integers). (By the way, the implementation I use for the pre-calculation is naive. Every digit-increasing number could be computed in one step from a previously computed one, for example `1+11+111` can be computed by adding `111` to the previously computed `1+11`. But it doesn't matter much because you do the pre-computation only once). The **effect** of the pre-calculation is that later you can do millions of number checks, and each check is just a hash lookup.

Comment: You say  pre-calculation and I say it **search**, and question doesn't asked for multiple call of the function, just asked how can I do this, so, your exhaustive search (pre-calculation) and your hashing, together are answer to the question, and sure it's slower than normal exhaustive search (on same machine and language), which at most checks 172 numbers (if you are right about the exact number), but your algorithm always checks 172 numbers. Another disadvantage of your algorithm is using extra memory (compare to others).

Comment: @SaeedAmiri I think we are having this argument because you assume that the program is used only once, to do the calculation for one input number. In that case other solutions are better. But my assumption is that we create a program that is loaded once and then performs many checks. The question itself doesn't really make any statement about the scenario.

Comment: I said this because of current problem statement, seems OP couldn't solve it for any case.

Answer (score 3):

General representation is:

> n + (n*10 + n) + (n*100+n)...

If number look like sum of same digits then any digit can be represented as

> (1+111+...) * base_digit

. Assuming this we can use simple algorithm:

```
bool isDigitIncreasing(const int num)
{
    int n = 1;
    int sum = 1; //value to increase n
    while (n <= num) {
        //if num is (111...) * base_digit and base_digit is < 10
        if (num % n == 0 && n * 10 > num) return true;
        sum = sum * 10 + 1; //N*10+N where n is 1 as was assumed
        n += sum;  //next step
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple exhaustive search will work.

```
def is_digit_increasing_number(x):
    # n = 1, 1+11, 1+11+111, ...
    n = 1
    i = 1
    while n <= x:
        if x % n == 0 and n * 10 > x:
            return True
        i += 1
        n = n * 10 + i
    return False
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest possible way is do the addition (bottom-up), I'll use simple for loop:

```
List<int> numbersSum = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
List<int> lastNumber = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
for(int i=0;i<= lg n + 1;i++)
{

   for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
   {
      if(list[j] < n)
      {
          var lastNumberJ = lastNumber[j]*10+j+1;
          list[j] += lastNumberJ; // add numbers to see will be same as n.
          if (list[j] == n)
            return j+1;
          lastNumber[j] = lastNumberJ;
      }
   }   
}

return -1;
```

The important part is you just need at most `log n` iteration and also you can return sooner if all numbers are bigger than given number, this is `O(log n)` algorithm.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the log-n bound. (That's a base-10 logarithm, right?)

Comment: @jogojapan, actually it's not important to be in base 2 or 10, but I wrote it for base 10.

Comment: Ok, then maybe I don't understand it fully. I thought the point is that if a given number M is equivalent to a sum `n + nn + nnn + ...`, then the number of `n`'s in the last element of the sum cannot be greater than `log M`. Clearly that is true for base 10, because otherwise the final element would have more decimal places than `M` itself. How would this work with a logarithm on a different base? In particular a base greater than 10?

Comment: @jogojapan, You are right in the exact case and because of this I wrote my assumption was base 10, this is motivation to logarithmic order, but I wrote it in O notation, not exact notation, so in O notation there is no difference between log in base 10 or base 2 or ...

Comment: Oh right, sure. I meant the `lg n` in the code, not the `log n` in the big-oh notation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a python code.The basic logic here is that a digit increasing number if divided by a specific number between 1-9 gives a digit increasing number made of only ones.All the digit increasing numbers of 1 follow a specific pattern ie 12345678...

```
import sys
for n in range(1,10):
    a=1
    if k%n!=0:
        a=0
    else:
        g=str(k/n)
        j=int(g[0])
        for i in range(1,len(g)):
            if int(g[i])==j+1:
                j=int(g[i])
            else:
                a=0
                break
    if a==1:
        print "Yes,it is a digit increasing number"
        sys.exit(0)
print "No,it is not a digit increasing number"
```

Comment: I think this is more optimized than creating numerous digit increasing numbers and comparing the number we got against them

Comment: Maybe. There are still several computational steps for each number involved in your method, and the hash of my answer (that's what you refer to, right?) may well be in L1 cache, thus providing great speed. But, yes, your method is definitely very good. That's why I upvoted it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the shortest solution

```
 public static int isDigitIncreasing (int n)
        {       
            if(n<10)
            {
                return 1;
            }

            for(int i=1;i<=9;i++)
            {
                int tempsum=i;
                int previous=i;
                while(tempsum<=n)
                {
                    previous=previous*10 + i;
                    tempsum=tempsum + previous;
                    if(tempsum==n)
                    {
                        return 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            return 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ambiguitiy:** Are the values 1-9 repeating for themselves? (too lazy to google this myself)

If 1-9 are repeating then following should work. If not, and you want the code to work only on values > 10 then you can initialize `mult` with 10.

```
int i, mult = 1, result, flag;

for( i=1; i<9; i++ )
{
    flag = 0;

    while( result < TARGET )
    {
        result = result+(i*mult);
        mult   = mult*10;

        if( result == TARGET )
        {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if( flag == 1 )
        break;
}
```

After execution, `i` must contain the values for which RESULT is a repeating number IF the `flag` is 1. If flag is zero after execution then the TARGET isn't a repeating number.

I wonder if its possible that a number could be repeating for multiple values, just curious.

Answer (score 0):

Here `num` is the number and `n` is the digit

```
#include<stdio.h>

int f(int num,int n)
{
 int d=n;
 while(num>0)
 {
        num-=n;
        n=d+n*10;
 }
 if(num==0)
        return 1;
 else
        return 0;
}

int main()
{
 int num;
 int n;
 int flag;
 printf("Enter the number :");
 scanf("%d",&num);
 printf("Enter the digit :");
 scanf("%d",&n);
 flag = f(num,n);
 if(flag == 1)
        printf("It's in n+nn+nnn+...\n");
 if(flag ==0)
        printf("It's not\n");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think OP want algorithm without necessity of entering base digit

Comment: you can try it using one more loop for checking with each base digit

Comment: Why me? I dont need this algorithm)

Comment: @DenisErmolin : Sorry I meant OP actually , but it's my native typing style

Answer (score 0):

Let d(k) be 1+11+111+...+(11...11) where the last number has k digits. Then d(1)=1, and d(k+1)=10d(k)+k+1.

We want to test if d(k)*i = n, for some k, and for some i=1..9.

If we've computed d(k), then i (if it exists) must be n/d(k). We can check if n/d(k) is correct, by comparing n with ((n/d(k))%10)*d(k). The %10 makes the test fail if i is larger than 9.

This gives us a relatively terse solution: compute subsequent d(k) until they are bigger than n, and at each point check to see if n is a digit-multiple of d(k).

Here's a very lightly code-golfed implementation of that idea:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_digit_increasing(int n) {
    for(int d=1,k=1;d<=n;d=d*10+ ++k)if(n==(n/d)%10*d)return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
        if (is_digit_increasing(i)) {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int isDigitIncreasingNo(int n) {

    if(n<=0)
      return 0;

    int len = std::to_string(n).length();

    int vector1 = 0;
    int vector2 = 0;

    for(int i=1;i<=len;i++)
       vector2 = (vector2*10)+i;

    vector1 = vector2/10;

    if(n % vector2 == 0 && (n / vector2)<=9  )
        return 1;

    if(n % vector1 == 0 && (n / vector1)<=9  )
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
  for (int i=0; i<10000000; i++) {
        if (isDigitIncreasingNo(i)) {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 public boolean isDigitIncreasing(int number)

 {
  int sum;
  int size=calculateNumberOfDigits(number);

  for(int i=1;i<=9;i++)
   {
      sum=0;
      int temp=size;
      while(temp>=1)
        {
            for(int j=temp;j<=1;j--)
             {
                sum=sum+i*(int)Math.pow(10,j-1);
             }
            temp--;
         }
      if(sum==number)
       {
          return true;//Its a digit increasing
        }
    }

     return false;
  }

 public int calculateNumberOfDigits(int number)
  {
     int size=0;
     do
       {
             number=number/10;
             size++;
        }while(size>0);

       return size;
  }
```